# My website seems to load in a very "patchy" manner. Any way to fix this?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm new to this site, but I have heard Stack Overflow is the best and most helpful place. My question is really a CSS and html one (I think), so sorry if I am boring any of you experts...My website, http://RapReports.com, seems to load in a patchy/choppy manner that is very unappealing. It is based on a pre-coded theme that I do have the html/css for. Any idea what the problem might be? Perhaps the white background is set as a white image instead of just a white background?

I will be happy to post pieces of the code if you specify the tags you want to see.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a jquery preloader & display complete website after full load.

Comment: please post your tumblr theme's code

Answer (score 2):

It's a combination of a slow web-server, and 1.70 MB data in about 130 requests. What you could do:

1. Try to combine and minify JavaScripts
2. Clean up your HTML
3. Put CSS in a separate file.
4. Use a tool like firebug, and have a look at the network tab
5. And so on.. You will find resources at google.

Answer (score 1):

put your javascript on bottom of the page...